# How to add display:inline-block to jQuery fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm running into an issue where I am attempting to get inline-block elements to `display: none` on page load, but then I want them to fadeIn one by one in their original `inline-block` form. However, when I do a normal jQuery `fadeIn` the elements display as block.

My jQuery is like this right now:

```
function blueBoxDelays(){
    $('.fadeBlock1').delay(200).fadeIn(500);
    $('.fadeBlock2').delay(400).fadeIn(500);
};
```

CSS

```
.dark-blue-box, .light-blue-box {
    height: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    /*display: none;   ********I replaced the inline-block with this.
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}
```

Is there something I can do to the jQuery to get these to `fadeIn` as `inline-block` elements?

Comment: Any reason you can't use CSS Transitions instead?  (Like browser compatibility maybe?)

Comment: I figured jQuery would be the best way to do this, but I am open to either. There isn't an easy way to add `display:inline-block` to my classes?

Comment: I'm sure someone might know.  Maybe use [jQuery.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) before the delay?

Comment: try like this `$(".fadeBlock").css({"display":"normal"}).fadeIn(1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.fadeBlock').css('display','none');
    
    blueBoxDelays();
    
    function blueBoxDelays(){
 var delay = 0;
 $('.fadeBlock').each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(400+delay).fadeIn(1000);
    delay = 400*(i+1);
 });
   };
});
```

```css
.fadeBlock {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dark-blue-box{
  background-color: blue;
}
.light-blue-box{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock"></div>
<div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock"></div>
<div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock"></div>
<div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock"></div>
<div class="dark-blue-box fadeBlock"></div>
<div class="light-blue-box fadeBlock"></div>
```

***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/trspta1u/)***

Note:

Remove the opacity from `.dark-blue-box, .light-blue-box`

Comment: It doesn't allow any of the blue boxes to display. Your demo is definitely what I want though.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this work without the .fadeBlock css? I need this to be responsive.

Comment: Wait never mind. The jsfiddle you had worked for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve the desired result by using opacity with transition property.

initially it'd be

```
.fadeBlock1 {
   opacity:0;
   transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }

$('.fadeBlock1').css('opacity','1');
```

Comment: I believe this would not fix the elements size in the dom, it would only make it transparent?

Comment: The thing is I have 8 of these blocks and I need to set delays so they appear to come in one at a time. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: I hope you could  float that blocks instead of using display:inline-block;

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this??

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .dark-blue-box{
            display:inline-block;
            border:1px solid #19248c;
            background-color:#19248c;
            height:50px;
            width:50px;
         }
        .light-blue-box{
            display:inline-block;
            border:1px solid #6699cc;
            background-color:#6699cc;
            height:50px;
            width:50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='dark-blue-box'>
    </div>
    <div class='light-blue-box'>
    </div>  

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('.dark-blue-box').css('display','none');
        $('.light-blue-box').css('display','none');
        boxFadeIn();
    });

    function boxFadeIn(){
        $('.dark-blue-box')
          .delay(200)
          .fadeIn(500)
          .queue(function (next) { 
            $(this).css('display', 'inline-block'); 
            next(); 
          });

        $('.light-blue-box')
          .delay(400)
          .fadeIn(500)
          .queue(function (next) { 
            $(this).css('display', 'inline-block'); 
            next(); 
          });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can see it live here: http://optimumwebdesigns.com/services ... I'm trying to get the blue boxes to appear inline-block one after another with small delays.

Comment: dude i'm sorry but you have a lot of problems with the css designs of your boxes. Please run the above code and you will see its the exact thing you want. To achieve it first of all dont set `display:none`, let jquery do it like i did it in the above code, dont use `opacity` because jquery is already doing the fading operations. Lastly, if you want the boxes appear one after another after a short delay, run the above code and you will see how to do it.

Comment: I need this to work for more than two blocks though.The way this is setup it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
function blueBoxDelays(){
    $('.fadeBlock1').delay(200).fadeIn(500).css('display','inline-block');
    $('.fadeBlock2').delay(400).fadeIn(500).css('display','inline-block');
};
```